# Please help me fix my lwc tag synonym

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

I accidentally added the new [lwc](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lwc) tag – which was intended as a tag synonym for the new [lightning-web-components](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lightning-web-components) tag – to [lightning-components](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lightning-components) instead.

Aargh!

Could I ask that two kind folks go and vote down my erroneous tag synonym so it will be deleted here: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tags/lightning-components/synonyms

Next time I check in, I'll add it as a synonym for [lightning-web-components](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lightning-web-components) correctly (I promise). Or if anyone else has enough reputation to propose it themselves, you can do it here:
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tags/lightning-web-components/synonyms

Comment: Thanks to whoever did the first vote-down.

Comment: Looks like the lwc was removed for `lightning-components` as synonym and now it suggests as synonym for `lightning-web-components` so I upvoted for that!

Comment: You're welcome. I cast the first vote, then this morning I was able to suggest lwc for lightning-web-components. It's well on its way to being ratified.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your synonym is now officially voted in. I'd like to take a moment to thank everyone that helped make this possible (though they might not even see this answer).

Comment: Indeed. Thanks, folks!